# Location of launch and icon image files for XCode project with many targets

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I have a project with multiple targets, each building a separate app, but sharing some core logic across them. I also have a separate app icon and splash image for each one of these targets.

They're neatly located in their own app's respective resources folder, but whenever I add these images under Targets -> Summary -> App Icons or Launch Images, these .png files get placed under the project folder's root folder.

I would ideally want to keep the root folder clean and avoid filling it with dozens of images all specific to separate apps. I'd love to keep those images in the folders where I'm storing them right now, deeper into the project tree structure.

What's the recommended practice here? Is there any way of not keeping these pictures under root (I tried deleting them, no go) that's not a painful hack?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find the following link handy. It contains a project with multiple targets and different icons/images. Each target has it's own set of images and are assigned in their respective info.plist files which can also be edited from the Info tab in Xcode (next to summary). If your images are included in the target you chose, Xcode will find them automatically so you won't need to place them in your project's root folder.

http://cybersam.com/ios-dev/creating-multi-variants-of-an-ios-app-from-a-single-xcode-project

Comment: My "resources folder" is just a custom folder I created somewhere inside the project. Is there a predefined per-target location for that kind of data in an iOS project?

Comment: Are you specifying each icon file manually in each info.plist?

Comment: I have not manually changed the info plist files. My way of adding icons and launch images was a very basic dragging of the necessary images from Finder into the Target Summary screen.

I'm very open to a better way of doing this, if there is one.

Comment: I think the only issue with not placing those icon .pngs under the root folder is that XCode won't be able to give a custom icon to different targets under the target menu. Not really a big deal. 

As far as deploying and running the app though, it does work as you mentioned above.